# Execute Stored Procedure using Entity Framework Core 1.1 error "error": "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have the following user defined procedure to call a calculated data from database with 2 parameters to return an integer (Count(*))

```
 USE [QIIS2]
 GO

 PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp.GetCansTotals] 
     @startdt datetime2,   
     @enddt datetime2,
     @hospitalId int
 AS   
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;  

     SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCancelled
     FROM Cans
     WHERE (OperDt BETWEEN @startdt AND @enddt) 
       AND (hospitalId = @hospitalId);
END
```

The repository to call the procedure:

```
public IEnumerable<Can> getcanstotal(int @hospitalId, string @startdt, string @enddt)
{
    _context.Database.OpenConnection();

    DbCommand cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "GetCansTotals";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    IEnumerable<Can> can;

    using (_context)
    {
        can = _context.LoadStoredProc("GetCansTotals")
                           .WithSqlParam("@hospitalId", @hospitalId)
                           .WithSqlParam("@startdt", @startdt)
                           .WithSqlParam("@enddt", @enddt)
                           .ExecuteStoredProc<Can>();
    }

    return can;
}
```

and the controller:

```
[HttpGet("byParams")]
public IActionResult GetCanTotals(int hospitalId, string startdt, string enddt)
{
    var cans = _unitOfWork.Cans.getcanstotal(hospitalId, startdt, enddt);
    return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CanViewModel>>(cans));
}
```

The following is the EFExctensions.cs for ExecStoredProced and Maping:

```
namespace DAL.Extensions
{
    public static class EFExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an initial DbCommand object based on a stored procedure name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="storedProcName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public static DbCommand LoadStoredProc(this DbContext context, string storedProcName)
        {
            var cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return cmd;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a DbParameter object and adds it to a DbCommand
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmd"></param>
        /// <param name="paramName"></param>
        /// <param name="paramValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DbCommand WithSqlParam(this DbCommand cmd, string paramName, object paramValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd.CommandText) && cmd.CommandType != System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Call LoadStoredProc before using this method");

            var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = paramName;
            param.Value = paramValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            return cmd;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes a DbDataReader and returns a list of mapped column values to the properties of <typeparamref name="T"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IList<T> ExecuteStoredProc<T>(this DbCommand command)
        {
            using (command)
            {
                if (command.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    command.Connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        return reader.MapToList<T>();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the column values from the stored procedure and maps them to <typeparamref name="T"/>'s properties
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dr"></param>
        /// <returns>IList<<typeparamref name="T"/>></returns>
        private static IList<T> MapToList<T>(this DbDataReader dr)
        {
            var objList = new List<T>();
            var props = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties();

            var colMapping = dr.GetColumnSchema()
                .Where(x => props.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower() == x.ColumnName.ToLower()))
                .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName.ToLower());

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    foreach (var prop in props)
                    {
                        var val = dr.GetValue(colMapping[prop.Name.ToLower()].ColumnOrdinal.Value);
                        prop.SetValue(obj, val == DBNull.Value ? null : val);
                    }
                    objList.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            return objList;
        }
    }

}
```

When passing the request with postman:

```
http://localhost:56963/api/cansdatas/byParams?hospitalId=2&startdt=2016-01-01&enddt=2016-12-31
```

Error:

> "error": "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Could any one help??

SOLVED  Just removed the Execute stored procedure and used the following code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Can>> Get()
        {
            return await appContext.Cans.FromSql("GetCansList").ToArrayAsync();
        }
```

Comment: You're showing us a procedure `GetCanTotals` which takes three parameters - but the method you have is calling `GetCansList` (some *other* stored procedure, it seems) which appears to take **no parameters** - so you cannot provide parameters to a stored procedure that doesn't expect any .... or are you just simply calling the **wrong** stored procedure in your C# code???

Comment: You are right, I fixed the procedure name  NOW i get the following error    "error": "Could not find stored procedure 'sp.GetCansTotals'."

Comment: Your stored procedure is defined as dbo.sp.GetCansTotals. To me, that reads as database = dbo, schema = sp, stored procedure = GetCansTotals. Can you just define it as dbo.GetCansTotals and update your reference to match and see if that works?

Comment: You also define a DbCommand that you don't appear to use?

Comment: Thank you all for reply, I modified the procedure name to GetCansTotals, now this error  "error": "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: solved    https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-execute-storedprocedure-in-ef-core/

Comment: @walidyoussef You can post your solution to the problem as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED Just removed the Execute stored procedure and used the following code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Can>> Get()
        {
            return await appContext.Cans.FromSql("GetCansList").ToArrayAsync();
        }
```